# jquery/javascript object required error

Tags: jquery

I am working in an ASP .net mvc project. The weird issue is I am running a JavaScript/jQuery which randomly gives object required error. Sometimes it occurs but sometime it does not occur at all. What I am doing is making an explicit link click call to load a page as follows:

```
function LoadPopup()
{
    $("#page2link").click();
}
```

I call `Loadpopup()` in `$(document).ready()`

After the above gets executed, page2 loads and the JavaScript for page2 is trying to run but I don't know why suddenly page2's JavaScript throws error. I don't know exactly at what line it throws error. The break point comes at `MicrosoftAjax.cs[Dynamicfile]`.

I am wondering why my debugger does not hit the breakpoint that I placed in page2's JavaScript. The stackj trace however shows a list of "JavaScript anonymous functions" and also shows that these anonymous functions are called from `loadpopup()`.

Some more information. I am having a master page. `Loadpopup()` runs when mystartup.aspx loads, which inherits from the master page. Can anyone please help me in this regard? Please let me know if you need more detail?

Comment: I am the same user who posted the question. May be my ID is different now. To my surprise I dont get the javascript object required error whne I used firefox and even the firebug did not higlight anything and everything went fine. But I dont know why I am getting the error in IE alone.

Comment: Well, IE is definitely a different beast than FF. There is a FirebugLite plugin (http://getfirebug.com/lite.html) that you can load with your pages and it will give you some of the capabilites of FB in FF.

Comment: Well If I am not able to get the error in Firefox, then I am not sure if firebug helps in my case. The problem just comes with IE alone. Is there anything that I can do to debug in IE?

Answer (score 1):

Get Firefox and install the Firebug plugin. Load your page, activate Firebug for the page and then reload. You may receive instant enlightenment. If not, put a breakpoint a `loadpopup()` and step through the code.